# MVP service client proxy model generation tools?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, mvp

I was reading this article on using passive view design patterns with MVP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336019.aspx

In discussing how a UI Model should map to the service client proxy, he write

> Because Service Agent operations take in complex types defined under UI Model, Service Agent operations need to map from UI Model to Service Client Proxy Model when calling Service Client Proxy operations. When Service Agent operations need to return results back to Presenter, they would map from Service Client Proxy Model to UI Model after getting results from Service Client Proxy operations.
>
> **This could be a tedious job. However, there are tools available to map from one model structure to another model structure easily, so this become more of a one-time design job.**

My question is, what tools are out there for this? My google is failing. We're using VS2010, .NET 4, WCF...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very popular tool for this type of conversions is [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: This looks pretty cool, would definitely work, but is there anything that would just generate code for the mapping?